# missing delimiter problem when using math equation

Tags: math-mode

I'm facing this problem of "missing delimiter" but I can't catch my failure

```
\begin{ceqn}
\begin{align}
    \pi^'(s) = greedy(v_\pi) =  \underset{a \in A} {argmax} \bigg q_\pi (s,a) \label{greedy policy} 
\end{align}
\end{ceqn}
```

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example. What is ceqn? I don't recall seeing that before

Comment: @daleif I believe it's from the `nccmath` package, but I concur: a full MWE would be nice.

Comment: `\bigg` needs a delimiter, like ( to act on, but you did not provide any

Comment: @chsk probably, I've never used that package

Comment: thanks for you all for the fast response

Comment: @daleif: it is used for centred equations, when the `fleqn` option is in use.

Comment: `\pi^'` is a mistake. It should be either `\pi'` or, more tediously, `\pi^{\prime}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `\bigg` directive should simply be removed. For sure, it is the source of "missing delimiter" message.

I have no idea how or where the `ceqn` environment is defined. I wouldn't use an `align` environment as there's nothing to align in a one-line equation.

`\pi^'` is a mistake and generates an error message. You should write either `\pi'` or `\pi^{\prime}`. (If this were *my* document, I'd go for `\pi'`.)

Finally, define `\argmax` as a math operator and replace `\underset{a \in A} {argmax}` with `\argmax_{a\in A}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\DeclareMathOperator' and '\DeclareMathOperator*' macros
\DeclareMathOperator{\greedy}{greedy}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{greedy policy} 
    \pi'(s) = \greedy(v_{\pi}) =  \argmax_{a\in A}  q_{\pi} (s,a) 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```